# Android: How to get contact DisplayName by contact _ID?

Tags: android

folks!

Look I broke my mind with problem - 
how get display_name from ContactContract via _ID I got earlier???

---

Here is the code:

```
    public static long getId(Context context, String number) {
    long id = 0;
    String displayName;
    // define the columns I want the query to return
    final String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID};
    // encode the phone number and build the filter URI
    final Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
    // query time
    final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));

            // HERE IS GOOD _ID!
            id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
            Log.d("_TAG_", displayName);

            {
                //
                // v. N-1
                //
                Cursor cursor2 = context.getContentResolver().query(
                        contactUri,
                        projection,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null);

                if(cursor2 != null) {
                    // Cursor valid but string below got error "android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1 : )"
                    displayName = cursor2.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    Log.d("_TAG_", displayName);
                }
            }

            {
                //
                // v. N
                //
                Uri myPhoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                        Uri.encode(String.valueOf(id)));
                Cursor phoneCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                        myPhoneUri, null, null, null, null);

                for (phoneCursor.moveToFirst(); !phoneCursor.isAfterLast(); phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    // No steps inside!
                    String str = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.NAME));

                    Log.d(App.LOG_TAG, "ContactUtils.getId:  " + str);

                }

                if(phoneCursor != null) {
                    phoneCursor.close();
                }
            }


        } else {
            Log.d("_TAG_", "Contact Not Found @ " + number);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return id;
}
```

---

"v.N-1" and "v.N" are just 2 ones from a million attempts before.

See - I got _ID, so why it doesn't work back as valid query???

Answer (score 0):

Here is decision i found.

```
    public static String getDisplayName(Context context, long id) {
    String displayName = null;
    // define the columns I want the query to return
    final String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
    };
    final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id + "" }, null);
    if(cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return displayName;
}
```

It works...